# Unable to recognize object with Google Cloud Speech Library

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a problem of running NodeJS with Error: .google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognizeRequest#bucket is not a field: undefined.

And I have checked [NodeJS cloud Page](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/speech/0.10.2/speech/v1/data_types?method=RecognizeRequest)

There mentions that `RecognizeRequest` requires two Parameters (Config and audio), which are objects.

Config (Required Provides information to the recognizer that specifies how to process the request.)
This object should have the same structure as `RecognitionConfig`

Audio (Required The audio data to be recognized.)
This object should have the same structure as `RecognitionAudio`

- But I have put audio.wav file on GCP bucket, and so why it shows such error? And how to pass it as object?

here is the code that i decide storage, am I right?

```js
    // Import the Google Cloud client libraries
    const nl = require('@google-cloud/language')();
    const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech')();
    const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
    const bucket = storage.bucket(object.bucket);
    const dir = require('path').parse(object.name).dir;
```